# Guzzle 422 Unprocessable Entity error

Tags: php, guzzle, browserstack

I'm using browserstack screenshots API - https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/api The following curl is working:

```
curl -u "username:password" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json"  -d '{"browsers": [{"os": "Windows", "os_version": "7", "browser_version": "8.0", "browser": "ie"}], "url": "http://google.com"}' http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots
```

However, when I try the same call call with guzzle I get 422 Unprocessable Entity error.

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$request = $client->post('http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots', [
        'headers' => ['Content-type' => 'application/json'],
        'auth' =>  ['username', 'password']
]
);

$data = ['browsers' => ['os' => 'Windows', 'os_version' => '7', 'browser_version' => '8.0', 'browser' => 'ie'], 'url' => 'http://google.com'];
$request->setBody($data);
$response = $request->send();
dd($response);
```

Can you suggest how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a mistake in method. It should be `$client->createRequest` instead of `$client->post`
Also, I had a mistake in data being passed. Browsers should be array of arrays

There is another library that could be used with browserstack and guzzle: https://github.com/ksenzee/browserstack-screenshots-php

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$request = $client->createRequest('POST', 'http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots', [
        'headers' => ['Content-type' => 'application/json'],
        'auth' =>  ['user', 'pwd'],
        'body' => '{"browsers": [
                       {"os": "Windows", "os_version": "7", "browser_version": "8.0", "browser": "ie"},
                       {"os": "android", "os_version": "4.4", "device": "HTC One M8", "browser": "Android Browser"}
                ],
                "url": "http://www.lipsum.com"}'
]
);
$response = $client->send($request);
dd($response->json());
```

Answer (score 2):

To send JSON to the Screenshots API, you would need to format it as a JSON string.

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$request = $client->post('http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots', [
        'headers' => ['Content-type' => 'application/json'],
        'auth' =>  ['username', 'access_key'],
        'body' => '{"browsers": [
                           {"os": "Windows", "os_version": "7", "browser_version": "8.0", "browser": "ie"},
                           {"os": "android", "os_version": "4.4", "device": "HTC One M8", "browser": "Android Browser"}
                    ],
                    "url": "http://www.lipsum.com"}'
            ]
        );
```

You will then be able to view the progress on your [BrowserStack Screenshots](https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots) page.

For a guide on how to send POST requests using Guzzle, you can refer this documentation — https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/guzzle/latest/guzzle.pdf.

Comment: you pointed me in the right direction, thank you for the docs link

Answer (score 0):

In my case uses 'json' in options's argument (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/185183/porqu%C3%A9-guzzle-5-0-lanza-el-error-422-si-estoy-armando-bien-la-consulta#185192), example:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_url' => 'http://www.browserstack.com/']);
$request = $client->post('screenshots', [
    'headers' => ['Content-type' => 'application/json'],
    'auth' =>  ['username', 'access_key'],
    'json' => '{"browsers": [
                       {"os": "Windows", "os_version": "7", "browser_version": "8.0", "browser": "ie"},
                       {"os": "android", "os_version": "4.4", "device": "HTC One M8", "browser": "Android Browser"}
                ],
                "url": "http://www.lipsum.com"}'
        ]
    );
```